# How do I $watch multiple interpolated attributes in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I don't understand how to watch multiple attributes at the same time in the link function, so I create an object with all the parameters and I watch for it. But I noticed that the attribute in the link function is a string and not an object so I'm using angular.fromJson(val).

[All the example I found just use one parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913841/accessing-attributes-from-an-angularjs-directive)

Could you explain how to watch multiple attributes?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
I cannot use attrs parameter because I need to bind the attributes -- i.e., they require interpolation.  For example

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3" ng-repeat="image in currentSizeInfo.images" >
       <upload-file info = "{{getInfo($index)}}" foo="foo$index" ></upload-file>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I think that I have to use $watch

```
link:function (scope, element, attrs ) {
    scope.$watch('info', function (val) {
    // if info is and foo is .... do all the stuff
    })
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, so please correct me if I misunderstand. Are just want to pull values from multiple attributes on your directive? So say you have a HTML like this:

```
<my-directive attr1="data1" attr2="data2" attr3="data3" />
```

And you want to get the values  of those different attributes? In the link function, you just use the attrs parameter. For example:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var foo1 = attrs.attr1;
    var foo2 = attrs.attr2;
    var foo3 = attrs.attr3;
}
```

You can also use the scope property on the directive to automatically bind attributes to your scope. See [their documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on directives. So, something like this:

```
scope: {
    attr1: '@',
    attr2: '@',
    attr3: '@'
}
```

And then those properties end up in your scope automatically. However, [as I found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645968/when-do-isolated-scope-properties-actually-get-added-to-the-scope), those values aren't always in the scope when you'd expect. So you can use the `$watch` function to do what you need with them. Something like:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch("attr1", function () {
         if (scope.attr1)
         {
              //stuff with attr1
         }
    }
    scope.$watch("attr2", function () {
         if (scope.attr2)
         {
              //stuff with attr2
         }
    }
    //....
}
```

If you need to use them all together at the same time, you could use a function for the first parameter of the `$watch` that returns a string that would be different once they are all there and then put your logic in the function that is the 2nd parameter. So something like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(function () {
        if (scope.attr1 && scope.attr2 && scope.attr3)
        {
            return "allSet";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }, function (newVal) {
        if ("allSet" == newVal)
        {
            //do stuff with all the properties
        }
    });
}
```

If you're wanting to bind objects into your scope, you can use '=' instead of '@'. Another option is '&' which evaluates a function in the parent scope. This is all explained in the directive documentation linked above.

Comment: Thanks dnc253; but I need to bind the parameters, so I think I have to use scope.$watch; but I don't know how to watch multiple parameters. I edited the question.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if I'm still not understanding something about your question.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, but I don't understand how to do the function to use all them at the same time. Could you write an example? Thank you

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rvd6x/3/

Comment: I've added another example to my answer. In your fiddle, you'll want to make sure prop1 is defined before trying to use it. It could get in there before it's defined.